# Temperature converter in Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, temperature

I'm doing a project which requires me to use a TinkerKit thermistor sensor to get the room temperature. After detection, the Arduino BT board must send serial data back to an Android phone via Bluetooth. And the temperature need to be display on the phone screen in Celcius.

I have already make the serial communication link work. But the reading from the thermistor seems weird. It reads at 173/174/175, but I'm not sure whether it read in Fahrenheit or Celsius (as I could not find any datasheet and details on the thermistor's reading unit).

Must I include any temperature convertor coding with the values?

The output values will be mapping @ : `outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's no data sheet for reading the thermistor, or documentation for the kit explaining what it returns? I'd guess the value you're getting is an unsigned byte (or possibly more than one byte, based on the '1023' value in your map) indicating the 'percentage' of temperature between two ranges.

Like if it were a single unsigned byte between -40'C (0) and +40'C (255), 174 would be 14'C (174/256 * 80 - 40) or thereabouts. You could probably do the math to figure out what the correlation is between the actual observed temperature in your room is and the thermistor value with a known-good thermometer as well.

Perhaps there's a library for the kit that interprets its values for you?

Comment: Hi, I just found and know that i need to download a Tinkerkit library first. After downloading and unzip into the Arduino library, i follow an example code for 'Thermistor'. i copy&paste the codes and the serial monitor display this : _Current Temperature:702 C:  173_ So after everything i still have use some math conversion for this?